# inserting data in two tables Simultaneously

Tags: sql

I have two table in my database , Position and Reservation that ID of Position is foreign key in Reservation. I want to insert data in reservation table but before this , data must be inserted to position table simultaneously . how can i do this??? can I use triggers or store procedure???

Comment: what is the data structure of your tables ? what did you try ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your tables look like this:

```
position: int id
reservation: int id, int position_id
```

First you've got to have a look at your foreign key `position_id`. If it has a `NOT NULL` constraint, you won't be able to create a `reservation` entry without before creating a `position` entry.

Using "normal" SQL queries, it's *not* possible to insert data into two tables with a single query.

Why do you need it to happen within one query? Because of data integrity? Then use transactions!

Comment: I try to design a system that a user can reserve a ticket of football competition . so when user insert his data into reservation table simultaneously should fill position that he bought!! for this reason I try insert user information into reservation table and before this fill position table!!!

Comment: This doesn't sound right!! Create all the position when you create the football competition, not when the user creates his reservation!! I think you should rethink your data structure design!! Or you tell us, **why** the reservation should happen before creating the position!! Else I just can repeat myself: Use transactions!!

Comment: I know this is not logical but creating all the positions of all venues is boring !!!